# Does there infinitely many such pairs for representing power of $3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $u,x_k,t,r\in \mathbb{Z_+}$ and 
$$\sum_{1\le k \le u}x_k^2=3^t  $$

Where $x_i\ne x_j$ and $\gcd(x_1,x_2,...,x_u)\ne 3^r$ for $1\le i,j\le u$

Found some pair for above representation such as $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(1,4,8)$ which shows

$$1^2+4^2+8^2=3^3$$

and $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(3,7,8,11)$

**Question**

> > can it be shown that, there are infinity many such pairs exist?

*Note*

Idea came from JMoravitz's comment in my old post and mathlove shows complete proof for $\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^{2}\ne 3^t \;\forall n,d,u,t\in\mathbb{N} $ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3388508/647719)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [Lagrange's four square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem), we know that any number can be expressed as the sum of four squares.  Given $3^t$, you can find many numbers $k$ such that $\frac 123^t \lt k^2 \lt 3^t$.  For each of them you can express $3^t$ as the sum of $k^2$ and four squares.  Making $k$ large guarantees it does not match any of the other squares, though the smaller numbers may be reused.  You can extend this idea as much as you want.  We also know there are numbers that are the hypotenuse of arbitrarily many Pythagorean triangles, so if you choose $k$ to be one of them you can replace $k^2$ with two squares in lots of ways.

Comment: Thank you, but can we prove, there are infinity many pairs for $3^t$

Comment: I don't know what pairs you are talking about.  Your examples have three and four squares. For a given $t$ you can only express $3^t$ as a sum of squares in finitely many ways.  I show that if you are given a number of ways you can find a $t$ to express it at least that many ways.