# Can a sum of first consecutive $n$th numbers ever equal a power of three?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Define $S(n)=1+2+3+\dots+n$

*Note:* $S(2)=3$

> Is the following claim true?
>
> For all $n>2$, there is no such $S(n)=3^t$ where $t$ positive integer?

Small attempt, let $S(n)=\frac{n(n+1)}2=3^t$ then $\frac{S(n)}{S(2)}=3^{t-1}=\frac{n(n+1)}6$ consider $n=3k+1$ then $\frac{n(n+1)}6$ never been an integer.
So we can conclude $n$ at least not equal to $3k+1$

Source code Pari/GP

```
for(n=1,3000,for(t=1,10,if(sum(i=1,n,i)==3^t,print([n,t])))) 

[2, 1]
```

Related post :[Do the squares of an arithmetic progression ever sum to a power of three?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3388508/647719)

Comment: $n$ and $n+1$ have no factors in common. So even if one of them is a power of three or twice a power of three, the other one can't be. (This argument shows that $S(n)$ can't be a power of any prime if $n>2$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\gcd(2,3^t)=1$ so if $n(n+1)/2=3^t$ then $2\cdot 3^t=n(n+1)$ and can see one of $n,n+1$ must be $2$ which means either $n=2$ [OK gives $n+1=3=3^1$] or $n+1=2$ so $n=1$ giving $n(n+1)=2$ which isn't a power of $3.$

Answer (score 2):

Now

$n(n+1)=2×3^t$

So now one of $n,n+1$ must be divisible be 3, and so because they are consecutive other will not be divisible by three
Let $3|n$ and not $n+1$ (the other case follows the same proof)

$3^t|n(n+1)$ and as $gcd(n+1,3)=1$

$3^t|n$ and $n=3^t×k$

Substituting in the original...

$2 = k(n+1)$ and now it's obvious...