# Not represent prime power?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Question**: Is the following claim true?

Let $p$ be the odd prime then

$$\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^{p-1}\ne p^t \ \ \ \ \forall n,u,d,t\in\mathbb{N}$$

[Proof for $p=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3388508/647719)

also have claimed

$$\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^{(p-1)m}\ne p^t \ \ \ \ \forall n,u,m,d,t\in\mathbb{N}$$

*I apologize for the deleted update claim because I received some error. I will not let this happen again*

**Formula**

$$\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^{m}=\sum_{i=0}^{m} \binom{u+1}{i+1}\sum_{j=i}^{m}\binom{m}{j}n^{m-j}d^j\sum_{k=0}^{i}(i-k)^j(-1)^k\binom{i}k $$

Where $n,d\in \mathbb{R}$ and $u,m\in \mathbb{Z^*}$ and $0^0=1$

Proof :  [Formula for $\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^{m}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3476906/647719)

Related posts

[Extending Fermat's Last Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3479623/647719)

[Can a sum of consecutive $n$th powers ever equal a power of two?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3369713/647719)

https://mathoverflow.net/q/348186/149083

*I may not have tried much that you could reject using counter example*

Comment: I am currently checking $n,u,d,t$ in the range $[1,50]$ and $p$ in the range $[3,50]$ without finding a counter example yet.

Comment: Finished with no counter example, now I check upto $100$

Comment: @Peter thank you so much, can you share your algorithm

Comment: PARI/GP : for(n=1,100,for(u=1,100,for(d=1,100,for(t=1,100,forprime(p=3,100,if(sum(q=0,u,(n+q*d)^(p-1))==p^t,print([n,u,d,t,p])))))))

Comment: Still no counterexample, but range $100$ not yet finished

Comment: parforvec, parforprime,parsum,isprimepower @Peter .

Comment: Of course, $(n,d)=1\lor p\mid (n,d)$

Comment: `gettime();my(a=0);parforvec(X=[[1,100],[1,100]],gcd(X[1],X[2]),j,tmin=0;if(j!=1 & !isprime(j) & !isprimepower(j,&tmin),,if(tmin,forstep(u=1,100,2,);a++)););[a, gettime()]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I know:

- $\gcd(n,d)$ has to divide every term of the sum, and therefore the sum itself.
- For the sum to be a prime power, that means $\gcd(n,d)$ is 1,p, or $p^x~~~~x\leq t~~~~x,t\in\mathbb{N}$
- By Fermat's little theorem, we get that all terms except the ones that have a factor of $p$ will have remainder 1, on division by $p$ ( there needs to be a multiple of $p$ of these in the sum for it to work out).
- Because the sum of two odd multiples, is an even multiple of any given number; we know that an odd number of terms must exist, that are odd multiples of the gcd above; any time $p\neq 2$.

Comment: Thanks, what can we conclude from this.

Comment: well if my above code gave consistent values on reordering tests I'd say just 60719 pairs (n,d) in the first million pass these criteria.

Comment: Actually I need some time to learn pari\gp and focus on given post. Can you please comment, are my claims false or true?

Comment: I don't know, however I'd teach you what I know of PARI GP.

Comment: @Pruthviraj if you want help learning just invite me to a chat.