# Can it be shown, $n^4+(n+d)^4+(n+2d)^4\ne z^4$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

We know, $n^4+(n+d)^4= z^4$ has no solution in positive integers $n,d,z$.

Can it be shown, $n^4+(n+d)^4+(n+2d)^4= z^4$ has no solution in positive integers $n,d,z$?

*I am check upto $1\le n, d, z\le 150$ without finding a counter example.*

PARI/GP

```
for(n=1,150,for(d=1,150,for(p=1,150,if(sum(q=0,2,(n+q*d)^4)==p^4,print([n,d,p])))))
```

[Generalization over problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3479623/647719)

Comment: Good question! As evidence to the hypothesis that there are no solutions, the smallest example of three fourth powers summing to a fourth power is already $95800^4+217519^4+414560^4=422481^4$. Since finding such examples is already very hard, I expect there are no examples with an arithmetic progression. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture

Comment: This is equivalent to findings rational points on the curve $x^4+(x+y)^4+(x+2y)^4=1$. This curve, I believe, has genus $3$ and hence contains only finitely many rational points, by Falting's theorem. Unfortunately I don't know any software that can find all rational points on a curve with genus $>1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, assume there's at least one solution and then let $m = n + d$, with $m$ being the smallest positive integer which works. The equation then becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
z^4 & = (m - d)^4 + m^4 + (m + d)^4 \\
& = m^4 - 4md^3 + 6m^2d^2 - 4m^3d + d^4 + m^4 + \\
& \; \; \; \; m^4 + 4md^3 + 6m^2d^2 + 4m^3d + d^4 \\
& = 3m^4 + 12m^2d^2 + 2d^4
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Next, note $a^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ for all integers $a$ which aren't a multiple of $3$. The right side of \eqref{eq1A} is congruent to $2d^4$ modulo $3$, i.e., $2$ if $d$ is not a multiple of $3$, which is not possible so $d$ must be a multiple of $3$.

Thus, the right side of \eqref{eq1A} has a factor $3$, so $z$ is also a multiple of $3$, which means the left side has at least $4$ factors of $3$. If $m$ is not a multiple of $3$, then the right side has only $1$ factor of $3$ (since $12m^2d^2 + 2d^4$ has at least $3$ factors of $3$), which is not possible. Thus, $m$ must also be a multiple of $3$. This means we can divide both sides of \eqref{eq1A} by $3^4 = 81$, which is equivalent to dividing $z$, $m$ and $d$ each by $3$ to, say, the $3$ integers $z_1 = \frac{z}{3}$, $m_1 = \frac{m}{3}$ and $d_1 = \frac{d}{3}$, which then results in

$$z_1^4 = (m_1 - d_1)^4 + m_1^4 + (m_1 + d_1)^4 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note this is of the same form as \eqref{eq1A}, but with $m_1$ being a smaller positive integer than $m$ which works. However, initially, I set $m$ to be the smallest such integer. This is a contradiction, so there's no smallest positive value for $m$ and, thus, no solution at all.