# Is there any solution for $n^x+(n+d)^y+(n+2d)^z=a^b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Is there any solution for $n,d,a,b,x,y,z,b\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ with $x,y,z,b\ge 3$ and $\{n,n+d,n+2d,a\}$ has least one common prime factor s.t.
>
> $$n^x+(n+d)^y+(n+2d)^z=a^b$$

*I think this problem help to enlarge [Beal conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal_conjecture).*

---

Related post

[Can it be shown, $n^4+(n+d)^4+(n+2d)^4\ne z^4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3481061/647719)

[Extending Fermat's Last Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3479623/647719)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT : answer with $d>0$.

Yes, there is !
Let $d=a=n=36$ and $x=y=z=3$ and $b=4$.

Comment: Note $d\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ shows positive integers.

Comment: Ok, your notation is ambiguous. I am used to the convention $\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{N}^*\cup 0$.

Comment: Now i fixed it.

Comment: Edited with $d$ non-zero.

Comment: Thank you now check normalising above problem https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3484458/647719

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fairly general solution, including for where you have more terms on the left side. Consider your [Normalising Beal's conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3484458/normalising-beals-conjecture) question's equation of

$$\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^{m_{q}} = a^b \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Choose any $u \ge 1$ and $c \gt 2$. Then have

$$m_{q} = c, \; 0 \le q \le u \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Next, have

$$n = d = \sum_{q=0}^{u}(1+q)^c  \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

The LHS of \eqref{eq1A} now becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^{m_{q}} & = \sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^{c} \\
& = \sum_{q=0}^{u}n^c(1+q)^{c} \\
& = n^c\left(\sum_{q=0}^{u}(1+q)^{c}\right) \\
& = n^c(n) \\
& = n^{c+1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Thus, you can choose $a = n$ and $b = c + 1$ so this matches the RHS of \eqref{eq1A}.

Your question here uses $u = 2$ in \eqref{eq1A}. Also, this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3484404/602049) is a special case of my solution, with it using $c = 3$. Thus, based on \eqref{eq3A}, you get $n = d = 1 + 2^3 + 3^3 = 1 + 8 + 27 = 36$, with the rest following as stated in that answer.

Comment: Thanks it's nice, Do you think for other cases may true

Comment: @Pruthviraj You're welcome. I'm not sure about your generalization. I believe it'll be quite difficult to prove that, in all cases, at least some of the values must always have a common factor. Nonetheless, good luck with making more progress on that question and, perhaps, getting a definitive answer some day.