# If $u$ is prime then $\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^3= a^3 $ has least one solution?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Question**: Is the following claim true?

Let $n,u,d,a\in \mathbb{N}$

Claim(1): If $u$ is prime then
$\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^3= a^3  $ has least one solution.

Claim(2): If $u$ is composite then $\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^3= a^3  $ has no solution.

**Example**

Showing one pair for some prime $u$

For $u=2$ allow $(n,d,a)=(3,1,6)$

For $u=3$ allow $(n,d,a)=(3,11,20)$

For $u=5$ allow $(n,d,a)=(31,2,66)$

For $u=7$ allow $(n,d,a)=(28,13,168)$

And

For $u=19$ allow $(n,d,a)=(3,1,40)$

Comment: $9$ is composite: try $u = 9$, $n = 15$, $d = 37$, $a = 495$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks, it's done...

Comment: @RobertIsrael professor, should I delete this post?

Comment: No, please don't.  It's still an interesting question: for what $u$ does a solution exist?

Comment: @RobertIsrael intresting think, i also claim for power greater than 3 there are no solution for any $u$ ,check-            https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3479623/647719

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\sum_{q=0}^u (n+qd)^3 = \frac{u+1}{4} (2n+du)(2n^2 + 2 d n u + d^2(u+1))$$
If $x = n/a$ and $y = d/a$, your equation becomes
$$ \frac{u+1}{4} (2 x + u y) (2 x^2 + 2 u x y + (u+1) y^2) - 1 = 0$$
where you want $x$ and $y$ to be positive rationals. This is an elliptic curve in $x$ and $y$, which can be transformed into the Weierstrass form
 $$ s^3 + t^2 + 64\,{u}^{10}+640\,{u}^{9}+2688\,{u}^{8}+6144\,{u}^{7}+8256\,{u}^{6}+
6528\,{u}^{5}+2816\,{u}^{4}+512\,{u}^{3} = 0
$$
by
$$ x = \frac{-8 u^5 - 48 u^4 - 104 u^3 - 96 u^2 - 32 u - t}{(2 u^2 + 6 u + 4) s},
\ y = \frac{t}{(u^2 + 3 u + 2) u s} $$
There are ways to find the rational points on elliptic curves...

Comment: Thanks, Actually I need to study the elliptical curves so I will accept your answer in a few days