# For all $m$ there exist $b$ s.t. $b^m=\sum a_i^m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can it be shown that there exist least one pair for every $m$ such that

$$a_1^m+a_2^m+\cdots+a_n^m=b^m$$

Where $a_i,b,m,n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ and $a_i\ne a_j $ for $1\le i,j\le n$ and $n>1$

Example:

$$\begin{split}1+2+7&=10\\1^2+2^2+3^2+5^2+19^2 &=20^2\\ 3^3+4^3+5^3&= 6^3\\ 30^4+120^4+272^4+315^4&=353^4\\ 7^5+43^5+57^5+80^5+100^5&=107^5\end{split}$$

Comment: Intuitively yes, but I don't see how you prove that. Good question.

Comment: By Fermat's Last Theorem, you know $m>2 \Rightarrow n\ge 3$

Comment: Maybe it's help, I claim $$\sum_{q=0}^{u}(n+qd)^m\ne a^m \ \ \ \ \forall n,u,d,a\in\mathbb{N}, \ \ \ \ m\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 4}  $$ in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3479623/647719

Comment: Now posted to MO link https://mathoverflow.net/q/358547/149083

Answer (score 2):

For cubes there are infinitely many solutions, e.g. using Ramanujan's identity

$$ (3 a^2+5 a b-5 b^2)^3 + (4 a^2-4 a b+6 b^2)^3 + 
(5 a^2-5 a b-3 b^2)^3 = (6 a^2-4 a b+4 b^2)^3
$$

There are similar identities involving some other powers (e.g. see [here](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/Home)), but I don't know
of anything that works for arbitrary powers.

An example for $7$'th powers found by Mark Dodrill:
$$ 127^7 + 258^7 + 266^7 + 413^7 + 430^7 + 439^7 + 525^7  = 568^7$$

An example for $8$'th powers found by Scott Chase:

$$90^8 + 223^8 + 478^8 + 524^8 + 748^8 + 1088^8 + 1190^8 + 1324^8 =  1409^8$$

$9$'th and $10$'th from Jaroslaw Wroblewski:

$$42^9 + 99^9 + 179^9 + 475^9 + 542^9 + 574^9 + 625^9 + 668^9 + 822^9 + 851^9 = 917^9$$

$$62^{10} +115^{10} +172^{10} +245^{10} +295^{10} +533^{10} +689^{10} +927^{10} +1011^{10} +1234^{10} +1603^{10} +1684^{10} = 1772^{10}$$

Comment: Thanks professor. Do you believe that there exist pair for 6'th power?

Comment: Yes, one of examples for $m=6$ is $$8^6 + 12^6 + 30^6 + 78^6 + 102^6 + 138^6 + 165^6 + 246^6 = 251^6,$$ and there exist many another ones (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation6thPowers.html).