# Can sum of even power ever equal to even power?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

Can it be shown that there is no such pair exist for any $u,m>1$ such that

$$n^{2m}+(n-d)^{2m}+(n-2d)^{2m}+\cdots+(n-ud)^{2m}=a^{2m}$$

Where $n,u,d,m,a\in \mathbb{Z}_+$

There are lots of example easily found for $m=1$ but not getting for $m>1$.

Example for $m=1$, $1^2+(1-1\cdot2)^2+(1-2\cdot2)^2+(1-3\cdot2)^2=6^2$

Source code(pari\gp)

```
for(n=1,50,for(u=2,10,for(d=1,10,for(m=1,5,for(a=1,50,if(sum(q=0,u,(n-q*d)^(2*m))==a^(2*m),print([n,u,d,m,a])))))))
```

---

Edit

Related claim (which was already posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3479623/647719))

Can it be shown that there is no such pair exist for any $m\ge 4$ such that

$$\sum_{q=0}^u(n+qd)^{m}=a^{m}$$

Where $n,u,d,m,a\in\mathbb{Z}_+$

By related claim allow, there is no such pair exist for $m>1$ such that

$$n^{2m}+(n+d)^{2m}+\cdots+(n+ud)^{2m}=a^{2m}$$

Comment: Is it not trivial to see that from Fermat's Last Theorem? e.g., u=1, we know that there is no integer solution for m>1.

Comment: I guess you were perhaps referring to Euler sum? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture

Comment: @NivPai no if you put $u=1$ then there are infinity many solutions with $n=d=a$. Clearly if given claim true then $\sum_{q=1}^{u}(n-qd)^{2m}\ne a^{2m}$. And thanks for your reference to sum of  powers conjecture.